# Is the relation $\geq$ always a partial order for the real numbers and integers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I was looking at particular examples and I observed that they were always reflective, antisymmetric and transitive.

Comment: And so are $\leq$, $=$.

Comment: @copper.hat I would think that equality "$=$" is not antisymmetric ;-)

Comment: I was trying to be discrete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, it is (if you're using the $\ge$ relation that I think you are). In fact, it's a *total* order, since comparability holds, as well.

Comment: so is it a partial order or what? they're suggesting that it's not.

Comment: *If the relation is defined in the way I suspect it is*, then it is a partial order. Just in case I'm thinking of the wrong one, how are you defining the relation?

Comment: In particular, I was assuming the natural order of the real numbers induced the relation. That gives a (non-strict) total order. It also totally orders every subset of the reals, and so partially orders them.